# Updating crontab from a makefile

Tags: bash, unix, makefile, cron

I'm trying to update the crontab from a GNU Make file.
The idea is like this: I look through the existing cron table and filter out all entries marked as mine (via the comment) and save that to a temporary file. Then I add my jobs to that temporary file and make it a new cron table. That way the make file can be run several times without harming other people's jobs.

This is the relevant part of the make file:

```
crontab.tmp: $(CRON_FILES)
    @echo -n "Generating new cron table combining existing one with a new one ..."
    if $$(crontab -l); then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > $@
    @cat $(CRON_FILES) | awk '{print $$0, " ## MAX-CRON-JOB"}' >> $@
    @echo "OK"

.PHONY: cronjobs
cronjobs: crontab.tmp
    @echo -n "Installing cron commands... "
    @crontab $<
    @echo "OK"
```

The troubling part is this line:

```
if $$(crontab -l); then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > $@
```

When the cron table is empty it somehow breaks the make, while the respective generated bash command:

```
if $(crontab -l); then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > crontab.tmp
```

Works OK from the command line.

Here is an error from the make (nothing particularly informative, if you ask me...):

```
Generating new cron table combining existing one with a new one ...if $(crontab -l); then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > crontab.tmp
make: *** [crontab.tmp] Error 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I resolved the issue. The way I did it, however, makes no sense even to me, so I won't post my solution. I can't really explain it anyway, so my main mistake was using Make and bash for this purpose in the first place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you 'escaping' crontab? As far as I can tell,

```
if crontab -l; then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > $@
```

should work fine.

Why use a conditional at all? If the cron table is empty, so be it:

```
crontab.tmp: $(CRON_FILES) 
    @echo -n "Generating new cron table..."
    @crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB" > $@ 
    @cat $(CRON_FILES) | awk '{print $$0, " ## MAX-CRON-JOB"}' >> $@ 
    @echo "OK"
```

Comment: And if there is nothing in the crontab file, you may get an error status from grep, so you probably need to add '|| true' to the end of the 'crontab -l' line.

Comment: Well yes, the condition is mostly for making it a successful operation anyway, so make does not report an error, but I failed at it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line to include a test (square brackets):

```
if [ $$(crontab -l) ]; then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > $@
```

because, at least for me, this doesn't work at a bash prompt without it:

```
if $(crontab -l); then crontab -l | grep -v "MAX-CRON-JOB"; fi > $@
```

yields:

```
-bash: 0: command not found
```